# How should I translate the verb torawarenai?

Tags: translation

I'm not sure how to translate this in English. Is there anyone who can help me?
価値観にとらわれない客観的な視点の研究. My problem is the verb torawarenai, for which I cannot find the best equivalent in English in this specific context.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: What's your best guess?  How do **you** parse this verb?  We don't do translations here, but we _can_ help you with yours.  Right now, your post doesn't even show the beginning of an attempt, and will probably be closed as "off-topic" (due to being only a translation request).  Edit your question to give us your current best guess, and we can help you with that.

Comment: This reads to me like the title of something and not a complete sentence. However, actually translating this title requires some imagination as to how the verb とらわれ(る/ない) fits into this context.

Answer (score 2):

～にとらわれる (捕らわれる or 囚われる in kanji) in this context is "to be hung up (on some idea)", "to be seized", "to be fettered", etc. The "bound" thing is your unfettered thinking rather than your body. Usually 価値観にとらわれる can be simply translated as "to be stereotyped".

> - 彼は形式に捕らわれて本質を見ていない。
>     He worries too much about style and ignores the essence.
> - 彼女は先入観に捕らわれている。
>     She cannot think out of the box.

Of course 捕らわれる can also mean being physically captured/arrested, e.g., 捕らわれの姫君 ("damsel in distress").

Answer (score 0):

We can't give you a bulk translation, but we can give you some hints.
The given phrase with 価値観にとらわれない客観的な視点の研究 is not sufficient.
It will be easier to be understood if it is written like:

- 価値観にとらわれない客観的な視点**で**の **〇〇に関する**研究.
- 価値観にとらわれない、**言い換えると、** 客観的な視点**で**の **〇〇に関する**研究.

The phrase is parsed as:
{価値観にとらわれない ＋ 客観的な視点での} 〇〇に関する研究.
Now, I think, you can translate the given phrase.